# How to declare dynamic slot function in Qt?

Tags: qt

First of all, sorry for my English.

Recentlly I'm working on a Qt project that supports plugins. In my program, I want to load plugins and create **QAction** instance for every plugin when the program starts. Then I met the problem: when the **QAction** instance is triggered, how can I know which one is triggered? (the *trigger()* signal of **QAction** has no parameters)

First I think about dynamic signal-slot connection using *connect*. But that requires dynamically declare slot function for every **QAction** instance. I don't know how to implement.

Then I have another idea. I try to implement a new Class **MyAction** which inherit **QAction**. And when it is triggered, I can emit my own signal with necessary parameters. Here's some code.

```
class MyAction: public QAction
{
public:
    int ID;
    MyAction();
    MyAction(const QIcon & icon, const QString & text, QObject * parent, int id)
    : QAction(icon, text, parent)
        {ID = id;}
    ~MyAction();

signals:
    void clicked(int id);

public slots:
    void trigger(){qDebug() << "triggered!"; emit clicked(ID);}
};
```

However, there's no "triggered!" in console.

I'll appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QObject::sender()` function will return the pointer to the object that has sent the corresponding signal. You can call it in your slot, like:

```
void onActionTrigger()
{
    QAction *action = qobject_cast<QAction *>(sender());
    [..]
}
```

I use `qobject_cast` here because `sender()` function returns a pointer to `QObject`.

Comment: That's what I need excatly! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can associate an integer, string or pointer to widget or object with a signal's sender using `QSignalMapper`.  Here's an (untested) outline of how to use it:

```
// connect actions to map
auto mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(mapper, &QSignalMapper::mapped, this, &Myclass::trigger);

for (QAction *a: actions) {
     mapper.setMapping(a, a->text());
     connect(a, &QAction::triggered, mapper, &QSignalMapper::map);
}
```

```
// slot implementation
void Myclass::trigger(QString text)
{
    qDebug() << "triggered by action" << text;
}
```

I've left out the template arguments to `connect()` - you'll need to add them to select the correct overloads of the signals and slots, but I didn't want to clutter the above code.